# making an video a screensaver on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, video, multiple-monitors, screensaver

So I'd like to make a video a screensaver on Windows 7 and am having some difficulty doing so.

So I converted my clip to a WMV and installed Photo Gallery and put the video - and just that video - in the `%userprofile%/My Pictures` - and set the Screen saver to "Photo Gallery" and the video plays but it's a 2 minute long video and only like 10 seconds of the video plays.

It also only plays it on the center monitor (I have three monitors) - it'd be nice if it played on all the monitors.

Any ideas?